# How to add pagination in wordpress when using this code?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm using this code to show post loop on my homepage.

```
<?php 

    if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

        get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

    endwhile; 
    endif; 

?>
```

And my `content.php` contain this code:

```html
<div class='post-outer'>
   <h2 class='entry-title'>
      <a href='<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>' id='pt'><?php the_title(); ?></a>
   </h2>
   <div class='pimg'>
      <img alt='featured image'  id='fimg' src='<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>'/>
   </div>
   <div class='post-inner'>
      <?php echo apply_filters( 'the_content', wp_trim_words( strip_tags( $post->post_content ), 25 ) ); ?>
      <a href='<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>'>[Continue Reading]</a>
   </div>
   <div class='clear'></div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to add pagination in this code by showing only 5 post at a time in loop and adding next page option in it.

Answer (score 0):

if you want with previous and next pages try this:

```
the_posts_pagination( array(
    'mid_size'  => 2,
    'prev_text' => __( 'Back', 'textdomain' ),
    'next_text' => __( 'Onward', 'textdomain' ),
) );
```

or if you want without previous and next pages:

```
the_posts_pagination( array( 'mid_size'  => 2 ) );
```

after **endwhile** and **endif** .

and for setting post per page, go to **Setting > Reading** and set number in **'Blog pages show at most'** field.

and here the complete pagination reference: [Pagination](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination)

hope to be useful!

Comment: Are posts displayed correctly?
and can i see your code after editing?